# Convert from non-binary to binary format for java memory dump

Tags: java, jmap, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Using the tool jmap, you can create a memory dump in two formats:

```
Binary format: jmap -dump:format=b,file=binary_dump.dat <pid>
```

or

```
Other format: jmap -dump:file=other_format_dump.dat <pid>
```

I've read a number of places that only the binary format is readable by tools like jhat and jvisualvm.

So:

1. Are there any tools that **can** read the other format?
2. Are there any tools that can convert from the other format to the binary format?

I have a memory dump file that was created using the other format and need to be able to examine it, preferably with the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool](https://eclipse.org/mat/).